# Retrieve the camera sensor dimensions

Tags: ios, photo

I'm looking for a way to calculate the camera sensor size using the iOS API.

Exif files contain the focal length and the focal plane X and Y resolutions, but I'm not sure how to retrieve the physical size of the sensor using this data.

Comment: Why are you after the size? If it's not possible, there might be another way to accomplish your goal. What's stopping you from keeping a list of devices and camera sizes in your app? There isn't many combinations to keep track of.

Comment: I need to do physical ray tracing. Sensor size is necessary in order to convert (i,j) pixel coordinates to (x,y) physical points. I suppose keeping a list in the app would be possible, but I'm after a more generic solution. Also curious about the calculation.

Comment: did you figured it out? I'm having a hard time trying to find it

Comment: Has anyone figured this out? Is it possible to find focal length on Iphone X? Not knowing this parameter makes developing AR apps impossible.